# Localization for a library module in Android

Tags: android, localization, shared-libraries

We are building an app that imports, via Artifactory, a collection of libraries that are then referenced from the main app.

We are in the process of localizing our app. We can localize our libraries and verify it works by directly using the libraries in a test app. When the libraries are pushed to our artifactory, we can then import, via gradle, the libraries for use in our app.

We can verify that making code changes or even changes to English strings in the libraries all work, and when pulled into the main app, any such changes are reflected correctly. However, while we have localized our libraries (into Spanish), when pulling the localized libraries into the main, the Spanish strings are not used. Instead, it uses the default (English) strings. We have looked at the libraries on our artifactory, downloaded the AARs and verified that the snapshots do in fact contain the localized strings but for reasons we can't figure out when imported into the main app, it does not use them.

We're confused why this is the case - wether we are doing something wrong or if there is a bug in gradle or Android.

Does anyone have any insight? I apologise for the vagueness but the issue is rather esoteric so I'm not sure what code if any might be relevant to solving the issue. Feel free to ask for further clarification.

UPDATE:

We decided to import the .AAR directly, by placing it in a libs/ directory and referencing it in our Gradle build. It now works fine, the library in question is correctly localized.

So it would seem the issue comes from when the snapshot is downloaded from the repository.

Comment: Does the main app have a spanish translation?

Comment: Yes it does, it has a values-es with the Spanish strings.xml in it. Is this a factor?

Comment: If you're doing changes in library, uploading, then trying to use in another project. It might just be that "another project" is using some old cached version of the library. Gradle have a command line argument for that case: try `./gradlew --refresh-dependencies`. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Budius, but I already made sure I was refreshing the dependencies when pulling new version of the libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app is looking at the wrong version of the library: the previously released version rather than the latest SNAPSHOT.

Full disclosure: James and I work together.